# How to merge Gradle and Maven Project into one app in spring boot using their application properties?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I wanted to join two workspace into one project app, using gradle and maven,and join them using application.yml/application.properties.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If so, what kind of problems did you encounter?

Comment: I am not clear on what you are trying to accomplish. Can you try to elaborate more?

Comment: I am trying to build frontend using maven project which will have its own controller, for the backend writing the logic in gradle that means it would be also having its own controller. Now can we join both the project into one so that when we debug the flow would be from maven controller to gradle controller. To do so what kind of changes we have to make in application.yml/application.properties.